# Syncing SharePoint metadata with Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet in a SharePoint Online library. The library has several columns of metadata, say A, B, C and D. The first two are text and next two are numbers.

I would like to do two things:

1. I have two named cells in my spreadsheet, Field1 and Field2, which are inputs in my spreadsheet model. I would like these fields to be automatically populated when I create a copy of the spreadsheet in the library. Ideally, if A or B change in SharePoint, I need Field1 and Field2 to be automatically updated.
2. Two more named cells in the spreadsheet, Field3 and Field4 are outputs of my model and I would like the SharePoint metadata C and D to be populated/ updated based on the values in these fields in my spreadsheet.

I am open to having VBA codes in my spreadsheet to achieve one or both of the tasks. Many thanks

Comment: It sounds like you have Sharepoint data hooked up to an Excel file (using Export to Excel), as long as this is kept linked you call pull through any updates from Sharepoint.  I don't know of a way to update your SP data from your Excel file though.  There used to be a function in SP 2010 called 'Synchronise' that would go from Excel>Sharepoint List, but it appears to be disabled (at least it is disabled for me).  It could be worth researching.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you develop some code to update the metadata
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Upload-a-file-to-f778988c
or 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3c0f7fc-d7d2-4eb8-bd12-821f4af49e60/uploading-a-file-to-sharepoint-by-programming-in-vba?forum=exceldev